# How do I display an expression with negative powers?

Tags: output-formatting

How do I display an expression with negative powers? Mathematica seems to always invert a term with a negative rational power. None of the following work:

```
Power[4,-3]
HoldForm[Power[4,-3]]
Unevaluated[Power[4,-3]]
```

The problem I am trying to solve is pretty simple. I have a function that takes an expression as an argument and returns two TextCells as a result. One text cell restates the expression and the other shows the simplified version of the expression.

I currently call the function like this:

```
f[HoldForm[ x^2 + 3x + 5 == 0 ]]
```

Ideally, it will display the original expression with minimal formatting (it is nice for Abs[x] to be replaced with |x| for example, but I'd like to leave negative powers intact).

**Edit:**

I just wanted to add, that I have a list of expressions to which I apply the expression to produce an "exam" document and an "answer key" document. That is why I need some control over the formatting of the expression. To the extent that a technique can be embedded in the function, that is probably preferable to having to change all of the expressions.

**Edit 2**:

I'd like to thank everyone for their suggestions. As Xerxes points out in his comments, Mathematica does not differentiate between the following two inputs:

```
x^-1 // FullForm
(* Power[x,-1] *)

1/x // FullForm
(* Power[x,-1] *)
```

Given this, I think the only way to achieve my formatting goal is to differentiate the input forms. Here is what I came up with:

```
xPower /: MakeBoxes[xPower[x_, e_ /; e < 0], form_] := 
    SuperscriptBox[MakeBoxes[x, form], MakeBoxes[e, form]] 
xPower /: MakeBoxes[xPower[x_, e_ /; e < 0], form_] := 
    SuperscriptBox[MakeBoxes[x, form], MakeBoxes[e, form]]
xTimes := Times
xPower := Power
```

Now, for my test case of `HoldForm[4^-3 \[Times] 1/2^-4]`, which Mathematica will by default rearrange to `1/4^3/2^4`, I can write:

```
HoldForm[xTimes[xPower[4,-3],xPower[2,-4]]]
(* 4^-3 \[CenterDot] 1/2^-4 *)
```

and,

```
xTimes[xPower[4,-3],xPower[2,-4]]
(* 1/4 *)
```

Using this paradigm, I need to use the alternate functions `xTimes` and `xPower` whenever I need to maintain the strict expression formatting. This seems like the minimum deviation necessary on the input side to achieve the desired result.

Does this make sense? Or, I am in for some unexpected behavior down the road? Did I miss an easier approach? Or, something more Mathematica-ish.

Comment: I think you forgot your definition `xTimes /: MakeBoxes[xTimes[x_, y_], form_] := 
 RowBox[{MakeBoxes[x, form], "\[CenterDot]", MakeBoxes[y, form]}]` in the above

Comment: In response to your second edit, I like the way you have done this. Possibly you can still use a function like doubleShow (below) to do default formatting and use functions like xTimes and xPower when you want to make an exception. For example you might make it so that `doubleShow[xDivide[c,d]]`-> c/d (with the c above the d, like a FractionBox), `doubleShow[c/d]`-> c/d (like how it looks here, i.e. with a RowBox) and `doubleShow[c xPower[d,-1]]`-> c \[CenterDot] d^-1 (with a RowBox and a SuperscriptBox). But really it depends on your preferences.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a combination of `Hold` and special Forms to do this:

```
MakeBoxes[MyForm[expr_], form_] := MakeBoxes[expr, form]
MakeBoxes[MyForm[Power[x_, p_ /; p < 0]], form_] := 
 SuperscriptBox[MakeBoxes[x, form], MakeBoxes[p, form]]

Attributes[doubleShow] = {HoldFirst};
doubleShow[expr_] := 
 Module[{}, Print[MyForm //@ HoldForm[expr]]; Simplify[expr]]
```

Resulting in:

```
doubleShow[4^-1 + 2^-2 + 2^1 + x^-2]
(* 4^-1+2^-2+2^1+x^-2 *)
(* 5/2 + 1/x^2 *)
```

Comment: I see you already implemented what I alluded to in my answer.  +1

Comment: This looks appealing, but it will take me a little time to understand it and implement it.

Comment: I got it to work for the given example, but now it seems to convert everything that it can with a negative power. `1/2` comes out as `2^-1`.

Comment: I see what you mean, but this is a bigger problem with the way Mathematica treats input. When you type `1/2`, Mathematica sees `Times[1,Power[2,-1]]`. There's nothing like a `Divide` produced, as you might think, so there's no way to discriminate between the two inputs you gave.

Comment: @Xerxes if you type 1/2 it is converted to Rational[1,2]

Comment: @RolfMertig I think that conversion happens later. Consider `FullForm[{1/2,Hold[1/2]}]`: `(* List[Rational[1, 2], Hold[Times[1, Power[2, -1]]]] *)`

Comment: @Xerxes here it is possibly also interesting to note that `Hold[Divide[a,b]]//FullForm` -> `Hold[Divide[a,b]]` (so that it is a bit confusing that "/" in the help points to Divide). But maybe you already realized this.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest is probably just using `Superscript`:

```
Superscript[4, -3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can use `Format` or `MakeBoxes`, etc., for automatic formatting.

Another example:

```
myFormat =
  TraditionalForm[# /. Power[expr_, r_?Negative] :> Superscript[expr, r]] &;

Abs[x]^-3 // myFormat
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is there a way to get the Superscript[4,-3] to evaluate as Power[4,-3]? For one use, I need to the unadulterated expression, but for the other I need to evaluate it. Edit: Sorry, I see what you mean now. Replace any elements that I don't want to change with an inert to evaluation element that displays in the appropriate manner.

Comment: This works for simple expressions, but when I apply this rule to 1/2^-4, Mathematica produces (1/2^4)^-1.

Comment: @RandomBits Point #1: Yes, you can use `Interpretation` for that, or `MakeBoxes`.  #2: I meant my "example" to be just that, not a complete solution.  I'll take another look at this later, but I think Xerxes may have already solved this. (I didn't test it extensively.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, probably you want to wrap within a bracket? A case where this is weird,
`1/(1-x (1-y)) //myFormat`

Answer (score 4):

```
Power[4, HoldForm[-3]]
```

displays as 
    [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Any reason to prefer this over `Superscript`?

Comment: Simple and effective -- this is probably useful in many contexts. The drawback for my application is that I have to very, very carefully write my expressions for this to work. One of my examples is 4^(-3) x 1/(2^(-4)). Putting the hold on the -3 keeps the first term from changing, but putting the hold on the -4 doesn't stop Mathematica from producing 2^(-(-4)). Adding a hold to the fraction fixes that, but I end up with four HoldForms for the simple expression.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Rolf Mertig's answer, it would seem useful to embody his idea in a function:

```
Attributes[pwrForm] = {HoldAll};
pwrForm[expr_] := Unevaluated[expr] /. Power[x_, y_] :> Power[x, HoldForm[y]]
```

Then it is possible to write expressions like these:

```
4^-1 + 2^-2 + 2^1 + x^-2 // pwrForm
```

> [image]

and

```
Abs[x]^-3 // pwrForm // TraditionalForm
```

> [image]

Comment: Applying this to my enhanced test case of `4^-3 1/2^-4` yields  $4^{-3-2 (-1)}$. I am not sure how that result is produced, but it is not what I expected. The default result from Mathematica for `HoldForm[4^-3 1/2^-4]` is $\frac{1}{\frac{4^3}{2^4}}$. The desired result is $4^{-3} \cdot \frac{1}{2^{-4}}$.