# Negative power instead of fraction

Tags: output-formatting, string-manipulation, polynomials, sorting

Solve returns a solution in the form `{{ x -> y / a^2 + y^2 / a^7 }}`.

Since I want to process the input (with another program) in terms of Laurent polynomials, I would like an output with negative powers instead of fractions:

```
y a^(-2) + y^2 a^(-7)
```

Is this kind of output format possible?

**Edit**: I would prefer a string `"x= y a^-2 + y^2 a^-7"` (or something that could be parsed to this easily)

Comment: Both `1/a^2` and `a^(-2)` have the same internal form: `Power[a, -2]`. It will be helpful if you mention what format your external program requires. Do you need to feed it exactly `{{x->y a^-2 + y^2 a^-7}}` (i.e., list of rules) or do you need only a string representation of the polynomial with the desired format?

Comment: Some useful starting points [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20566/how-do-i-display-an-expression-with-negative-powers)

Comment: Why was this downvoted and even flagged for closing as being "too localized"? I think it is a perfectly reasonable question given the aim of the poster (using external software) and is not trivial to solve based on the Documentation.

Comment: please see the link in geordie's comment, @user6772. Your question seems to have been answered there..

Comment: @rm-rf Might it be more correct to say the following, instead of your first comment above? `1/a^2` and `a^-2` both evaluate to `Power[a,-2]`. This is not the result of one internal step, as we have `Hold[a^-2] // FullForm` -> `Hold[Power[a,-2]]`, whereas `Hold[1/a^2]` // FullForm -> `Hold[Times[1,Power[Power[a,2],-1]]]`, which is just a "special case of" `Hold[a/b]`//FullForm -> `Hold[Times[a,Power[b,-1]]]`. Note that `Hold[Divide[a, b]] // FullForm` -> `Hold[Divide[a,b]]` (so that it is slightly misleading that "/" points to `Divide` in the help). ...

Comment: Convention could then be to say `a/b` has the internal form `Times[a, Power[b, -1]]`. That would be less misleading to me :P. Anyway it might be that nobody cares, or the convention is different than I would expect, or I'm just being some kind of terminology-nazi :P. Feedback welcome :). Oh and please don't look at my silly deleted answer below ;).

Comment: And we could say: `1/a^2` and `a^(-2)` both have/<get parsed to> internal forms that internally evaluate to (the internal form) `Power[a,-2]`. That way we can use evaluate in a loose way and use internally evaluate when we want to be precise. Whatever :)