# How can I keep the form of the expression when I use `TeXForm[HoldForm[]]`?

Tags: output-formatting, latex

I want to keep the form of the expression when I use `TeXForm[HoldForm]]`
$$(x^{-1} y^3)^2 \left (\dfrac{x^2}{2y}\right)^{-2}\left (\dfrac{-2x^2}{y^3}\right )^{-4},$$
But when I use

```
TeXForm[HoldForm[(x^(-1) y^(3))^2 (x^2 /(2 y))^(-2) (-2 x^2 /y^3)^(-4)]]
```

I got 
$$\frac{\left(\frac{y^3}{x}\right)^2}{\left(\frac{x^2}{2y}\right)^2 \left(-\frac{2x^2}{y^3}\right)^4}.$$
How can I keep the original expression?

Comment: Look at FullForm[HoldForm[your expression]].  Mathematica does not have a Divide operator, so there is no difference between the representation of x/y and that of x y^-1.  You would need to process the expression as a string to accomplish what you desire.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20566/how-do-i-display-an-expression-with-negative-powers  (since the problem has more to do with how *Mathematica* treats negative powers, than with `TeXForm` per se).

Answer (score 2):

Why does this happen?  Because Mathematica interprets both `x/y` and `x y^-1` as the same expression.

```
FullForm@HoldForm[x/y]
(* HoldForm[Times[x,Power[y,-1]]] *)

FullForm@HoldForm[x y^-1]
(* HoldForm[Times[x,Power[y,-1]]] *)
```

This happens during the [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) step, not evaluation. It cannot be prevented with `HoldForm`.

You can achieve your goal, but it requires some manual intervention.  Here are a few ways to trick `TeXForm` into producing different output than the default by inserting `HoldForm` into the expression at strategic positions:

```
TeXForm[x y^-1]
(* \frac{x}{y} *)

TeXForm[x y^HoldForm[-1]]
(* x y^{-1} *)

TeXForm[x/y^a]
(* x y^{-a} *)

TeXForm[x/HoldForm[y^a]]
(* \frac{x}{y^a} *)

TeXForm[HoldForm@Divide[x,y^a]]
(* \frac{x}{y^a} *)
```

Note: `Divide[x,y]` is distinct from `x/y`/`x y^-1`.  It *evaluates* immediately to `x y^-1`, but since this is now evaluation and not parsing, it can be prevented with `HoldForm`.

In certain cases it will be possible to insert `HoldForm` using [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html).  Otherwise it may be easier to just edit the $\TeX$ code manually ...  That is what I usually do.