# Axes labeling with superscripts

Tags: graphics, labeling

I need to label the y-axis of a plot with the form `a/GeV^-1`, where `^` denotes superscript. But *Mathematica* always write `GeV a` instead, interpreting `1/GeV^-1` as `GeV`. How to avoid this interpretation?

Comment: put it inside " ". `AxesLabel->{"x axis", "a/GeV^-1"}`

Comment: see: [20566](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20566/how-do-i-display-an-expression-with-negative-powers/20569#20569)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [$\LaTeX$ typesetting package](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html), `MaTeX`, written for such situations by [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs).

```
<< MaTeX`

Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10}, AxesLabel -> MaTeX /@ {"\\text{$x$ axis}", "a/\\mathrm{GeV}^{-1}"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit :-)  (feel free to revert)

Comment: @Szabolcs Of course not. Thanks for your corrections.

Answer (score 2):

In:

```
label = Row[ {"a/Ge", Superscript["V", -1] }];
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, AxesLabel -> label]
```

Out:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The answer is updated according to your suggestion. :)